spring boot 2.0.0 vault issues
I am upgrading my spring boot App from 1.5.0 to 2.0.0. After upgrade I am unable to read vault config from bootstrap.yml
My config as follows
   spring:
      vault:
      enabled: true
      authentication: TOKEN
      host: ${VAULT_ADDR:localhost}
      port: ${VAULT_PORT:8200}
      token: ${VAULT_TOKEN:eafaa220-901acaafffb5}
      scheme: http

and my build.gradle dependencies
springBootVersion = '2.0.9.RELEASE'
springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.SR4'

 compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas')
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-config')
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix')
implementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-vault-config')

While starting the app in local I am getting below exception
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'spring.cloud.vault' to org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultProperties:

    Property: spring.cloud.vault.authentication
    Value: TOKEN
    Origin: class path resource [bootstrap.yml]:19:23
    Reason: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty' validating type 'java.lang.String'. Check configuration for 'host'

Action:

Update your application's configuration

05 Jun 2024 09:53:19,637 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] (main) {} Application run failed

I am not sure what is missing and appreciate any help

I know it's not the answer to your question, but there is little to no sense in "upgrading" to Spring Boot 2, especially to the version 2.0.9  - it's been deprecated years ago. As of June 2024, the up-to-date version is 3.3.0.

Yes, You are correct but my ultimate goal is upgrade to 3.3.0. I do not want to take a direct jump and unsure of if something not working.

I mean, most likely your code will break anyways, so you might end up with double effort. I remember upgrading from 2.0.4 to 2.2.0 and even that was painful, so I'd expect your case to be even more complicated if you choose to use an unmaintained framework version as an intermediate milestone.

ok. Thanks for valuable suggestion then I will directly jump on upgrading 2.7.18 as I have only app running on Java8 and upgrading to 3.3.0 requires java17
